# Where can I find spring-ldap 1.3.1-RELEASE maven repo

Tags: spring, spring-ldap

1.2.1 is available, i can get it by

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version> 
</dependency>
```

but I can't get the latest build. I have used

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I am interested in using the authenticate method of LdapTemplate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like now they want you [to declare dependencies on individual modules](http://www.springsource.org/ldap).

However, the single module [is still there](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/ldap/spring-ldap/1.3.1.RELEASE/), but you need to use classifier to access it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <classifier>all</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks heaps! I was missing <classifier>all</classifier> :D

Answer (score 0):

It is available in the below link

[You can download it here](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-ldap/tags/spring-ldap-1.3.1.RELEASE/pom.xml)